# Kiel traduki „daŭrajn gerundiojn“ en programoj?

Tags: translation

Pardonu min, se la titolo ne estas ĝusta, sed mi ne povis elpensi pli bone. Bonvolu korekti ĝin, se necesas.

Temas pri traduko de programoj. Ĉe ili ofte estas tiaj frazoj, kiuj montriĝas, kiam oni devas atendi, por ke la programo faru ion:

> Downloading…
>
> Extracting…
>
> Installing…

Kiel traduki tiajn frazojn?

Mi vidis, ke kelkaj tradukas ilin tiel:

> Elŝutante… Maldensigante… Instalante…

Sed mi dubas… tio ŝajnas stranga al mi. Ĉu tio estas la plej bona metodo traduki tion? Ĉu ĉi tio pli ĝustas:

> Elŝutado… Maldensigado… Instalado…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mi mem uzis la formojn Elŝutado… Maldensigado… Instalado… kiam mi tradukis programojn. Sed certe Elŝutanta… Maldensiganta… Instalanta… ankaŭ taŭgas.

Answer (score 1):

> Downloading…

- elŝuti (tr) = download
- La programo **elŝutiĝas** = the program is downloading

> Extracting…

- eltiriĝas

> Installing…

- instaliĝas

Answer (score 1):

Se vi volas traduki laŭvorte, "Elŝutanta" estas la gramatika ekvivalento al la participo "Downloading".

Persone, por tiuj kazoj mi uzas la -ad- formon. La PIVa difino proponas "Verbojn el morfemoj signifantaj agon aŭ objekton, por prezenti la agon en ĝia malvolviĝo k insisti pri ĝia daŭro aŭ ripetiĝo". Al mi ŝajnas tute konvena por tiaj kazoj. Esperanto ofte eblas diri fazoj pli precize ol Angla, ĉar Angla ofte kontentas kun [simpla elvokado (Espéranto: le point de vue d'un écrivain)](http://claudepiron.free.fr/articlesenfrancais/ecrivain.htm).

Comment: La frazo konsistas el nur unu vorto kaj ne havas subjekton, do ĉu tio ne estu *elŝutant**e***?

Comment: Ambaŭ estas eblaj, kaj vi ĉiam povas interpreti unuvortajn frazojn kiel elipso. Tiu kaze, elipso de "dosiero estas alŝutenta".

Answer (score 1):

Oni uzu la nomon de la ago (la -o vorton) sed ne tiun de la daŭra ago, ĉar kutime temas nur pri tiu fakta nuna ago.

Loading... -> ŝargado...
Downloading ... -> Elŝuto... (kaj ne elŝutado...)

Kelkaj verboj kreas la nomon de la ago per -o kaj kelkaj per -ad-, la reguloj por tio dependas de la tipo de radiko, tial mi sugestas kontroli en vortaro.

```
Verbo    Nomo de ago

ŝargi    ŝargado
serĉi    serĉo
importi  importo
konservi konserv(ad)o (oni devus elekti la pli mallongan, pro sufiĉo)
```

Tion oni faru se ne estas objekto. Kun objektoj oni povas igi la frazon pasiva kun la -at- participo:

```
loading file...       dosiero ŝargata...
creating profile...   profilo kreata...
```